# Prevent column name from disappearing after using replace on dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, str-replace

So I have a real dataframe that somewhat follows the next structure:

```
d = {'col1':['1_ABC','2_DEF','3 GHI']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Basically, some entries have the **" _ "**, others have **" "**.
My goal is to split that first number into a new column and keep the rest. For this, I thought I'd first replace the **'_'** by **' '** to normalize everything, and then simply split by **' '** to get the new column.

```
#Replace the '_' for ' '
new_df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('_',' ')
```

My problem is that now my **new_df** now lost its column name:

```
0    1 ABC
1    2 DEF
```

Any way to prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) return `Series`, so there is no column name, only `Series` name.

```
s = df['col1'].str.replace('_',' ')
print (s)
0    1 ABC
1    2 DEF
2    3 GHI
Name: col1, dtype: object

print (type(s))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print (s.name)
col1
```

---

If need new column assign to same `DataFrame` - `df['Name']`:

```
df['Name'] = df['col1'].str.replace('_',' ')
print (df)
    col1   Name
0  1_ABC  1 ABC
1  2_DEF  2 DEF
2  3 GHI  3 GHI
```

Or overwrite values of original column:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace('_',' ')
print (df)
    col1
0  1 ABC
1  2 DEF
2  3 GHI
```

---

If need new one column `DataFrame` use [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) for convert `Series` to `df`:

```
df2 = df['col1'].str.replace('_',' ').to_frame()
print (df2)
    col1
0  1 ABC
1  2 DEF
2  3 GHI
```

Also is possible define new column name:

```
df1 = df['col1'].str.replace('_',' ').to_frame('New')
print (df1)
     New
0  1 ABC
1  2 DEF
2  3 GHI
```

---

Like @anky_91 commented, if need new 2 columns add [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df1 = df['col1'].str.replace('_',' ').str.split(expand=True)
df1.columns = ['A','B']
print (df1)
   A    B
0  1  ABC
1  2  DEF
2  3  GHI
```

If need add columns to existing `DataFrame`:

```
df[['A','B']] = df['col1'].str.replace('_',' ').str.split(expand=True)
print (df)
    col1  A    B
0  1_ABC  1  ABC
1  2_DEF  2  DEF
2  3 GHI  3  GHI
```

Comment: is there something where we can replace the `_` and split on spaces on the fly?

Comment: @anky_91 - Not understand, do you think `df['col1'].str.replace('_',' ').str.split(expand=True)` ?

Comment: yes i think OP wants something like this. :) this line: " I thought I'd first replace the '_' by ' ' to normalize everything, and then simply split by ' ' to get the new column" you can just add this as an option.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I upped everyone's comment and chose it as the final answer. Thanks!